# Chart.js - X-Axis scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, scale, axis

I am creating a graph using chart.js .

[image: picture of the graph]

I plot something on y-axis (let's say the number of active customers) and time on x-axis, but time is measured day by day for the first month (day1, day2 up to day30), then 30 days by 30 days and finally 180 days by 180 days.

My graph works but it isn't natural since the distance between two consecutive points on x axis (day1 vs day2, or day180 vs day360) is constant. I would like the space between day180 and day360 to be 180 times greater than the distance between day1 and day2.

I have tried to change the names from day1 to 1 and so on, it did not work.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about inserting empty datapoints in between?

So this concept:

```
labels = ["1", "2", "", "4", "", "", "", "8"];
data =  [65, 59, null, 81, null, null, null, 34];
```